# Boolean Valued Response in C++

Tags: c++

please, is there a way to get boolean valued response directly from users in c++??. For instance I would like a user to answer yes or no but I do not want to store the response in a character or string variable but directly into a boolean variable. Thanks.

Comment: What inputs mean `True` adn what inputs mean `False`?

Comment: Create a `numpunct`-derived facet that implements `do_truename` and `do_falsename` as desired, `imbue` it into `cin`, then you can read directly into a `bool` variable.

Comment: @sharth: whatever `numpunct` facet in the stream's locale says.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: They talk about the input coming from users. If I was building an input function that produced a bool, I might want `yes`, `y`, `true`, and `1` to all mean `True`.

Comment: @sharth: The OP says " I would like a user to answer yes or no". "y" and "n" would also work - the stream's input parsing does a prefix match against `truename` and `falsename`.

Comment: We're talking console input right? If you want an input of "yes" to set a bool to true, then you have to store it in a string or buffer of some sort, parse it, and then set the bool.

Comment: @sharth exactly!, like in Java TextIO's class.

Comment: @NeilKirk I get your point but my question was that, is there no direct way to get the yes or no into a boolean variable as opposed to testing the string and setting the boolean value?

Comment: There is no direct way. Suggestion: Use `std::map<std::string, bool>` to map possible inputs to a value.

Answer (score 1):

Declare variable as bool and take input as 0 or 1 to be treated as false or true respectively.

```
bool b;
cin >> b;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i reckon it's only limited to 0 and 1 right?

Comment: @OROBOGENIUS, in fact, 1 is interpreted as true here, and anything other than 1 is false (not necessarily zero), for any other value pair interpretation, you need to customize through your own customized class and its overloaded >> operator

Answer (score 1):

```
class ReadBool {
public:
  ReadBool(bool& v) : v_(v) {}
  void Parse(istream& is) const {
    string s;
    is >> s;
    v_ = (s == "yes");  // adjust to taste
  }
private:
  bool& v_;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, const ReadBool& rb) {
  rb.Parse(is);
  return is;
}
```

Now you can do

```
bool b;
cin >> ReadBool(b);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the trick perfectly, although somewhat extensive but am satisfied.